# How to find and match data in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have an Excel file which contains two sheets, one holds a list of specific usernames (say in column A) and the other one holds the complete list of usernames (column A) and also the cities (column B).

I need a formula to match usernames between these two sheets and then have the related cities next to the usernames at the first sheet, for example in column B of it.

Here is what I tried at column B of the second sheet but didn't succeed:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1&"", Sheet1!$A$1:$B$1000, 2, FALSE)
```

I've also replaced the first argument with A1+0 and also the second one without any $ signs if it helps anyway.

---

Here is the entire of my original formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B1&"", Sheet1!$M$1:$N$1170, 13, FALSE)), VLOOKUP(B1&"", Sheet1!$N$1:$V$1170, 22, FALSE), VLOOKUP(B1&"", Sheet1!$M$1:$N$1170, 13, FALSE))
```

It suppose to take the username from column B of Sheet2 (the first one described above which only has the specific list of usernames) and search for the match in column N of Sheet1 (the second described sheet which has username and city inside), then return the value of city which is placed on column M but if it has a #N/A error (which is probable), return the V column instead which also holds the city name on the rows those have no city name in their M column.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a VLOOKUP to look up the items from B in the list of A. If it doesn't find a match, VLOOKUP will return #N/A. You could also combine this with an IF statement so that if it's missing, it'll give you some message. For example, in C1 enter

=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B1, $A$1:$A$1957, 1, FALSE )), "MISSING", "MATCHED!")

and copy/paste this formula all the way down your column of "B" figures to check.

this will start by looking up B1 in the range of A1:A1957. If it does not find a match it will return NA. Then we combine this with an IF statement so that IF VLOOKUP results in NA, we give a message of "MISSING". If it's not NA then there it means we found a match, so we give a message of "MATCHED!".
obviously you can change the missing/matched message to whatever you like.
[best online MBA](http://aimsely.com/)

Comment: Thanks for response. Actually I've cut a part from the entire formula to here, the main one is more complex and there is an IF inside. I'll update the question with these details.

Answer (score 0):

A few comments:
1) Why: `B1&"",` ? Try: `B1,`
2) Both the lookup column 13 and 22 can't be possible if the lookup table is only 2 column's. So these values should either be 2, or you need to expand the column range up to the amount you wish to retrieve the data from.
You need to count the amount of columns starting from the first lookup column in your range so ... if the data to retrieve from column M to column N is in column N, then this should be 2. For N up to V, this should be 9. TRY:

> =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B1&"", Sheet1!$M$1:$N$1170, 2, FALSE)), VLOOKUP(B1&"", Sheet1!$N$1:$V$1170, 9, FALSE), VLOOKUP(B1&"",
>   Sheet1!$M$1:$N$1170, 2, FALSE))

Comment: Thanks. 1) Someone told me this is needed for type casting, so if you say, it seems to not be required. 2) The first part of my question was a simplified example of the whole thing which I've mentioned about at the second extended part. So the numbers are correct.

Answer (score 0):

In the original formula (from second part), your range starts from the wrong column: should start with the column which has the matching lookupvalue. I assume column A. From column A, it's 22 columns to V, and 13 columns to N. The correct formula should then be:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B1&"", Sheet1!$A$1:$N$1170, 13, FALSE)), VLOOKUP(B1&"", Sheet1!$A$1:$V$1170, 22, FALSE), VLOOKUP(B1&"", Sheet1!$A$1:$N$1170, 13, FALSE))
```

If for example you have the matching username in for example B, the formula should be:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B1&"", Sheet1!$B$1:$N$1170, 12, FALSE)), VLOOKUP(B1&"", Sheet1!$B$1:$V$1170, 21, FALSE), VLOOKUP(B1&"", Sheet1!$B$1:$N$1170, 12, FALSE))
```